# Detail/Edit Form For Class-Based Views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to build a basic Details form for one of the Django Models. However, when I click on an entry, all it gives me is just an empty form. What am I missing?

What's more, is there a better way to create basic Detail/Edit forms for existing models?

View code:

```
class ProjectView(generic.FormView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'steps/project-detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_title
```

Form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Project

class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Project
        fields = ['project_title','project_description']
```

Template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"
      rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<h1>Project:</h1>
<h1>{{ project.project_title }}</h1>
{{ form }}
```

Here is what the page looks like. I am also curious why the `project_title` is not displayed.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `UpdateView`?

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

Comment: @mishbah I have tried, but could not get it to work either.

Comment: Better to use `UpdateView` and let us know problem you see with it. Also, post your urls file as well.

Comment: I was able to get UpdateView to work. Is there a particular reason why it is better, aside from not re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: There's nothing 'better' about `UpdateView` than `FormView`, but if you use `FormView` to create model instances, you'll end up duplicating a lot of `UpdateView`'s functionality. It's usually not a good idea to override `get` or `post` in Django generic class based views - you can end up duplicating a lot of the code or missing out important functionality.